# How to make background image of a responsive (with shrinking of image)

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

i have developed a webpage where i am using a background image for a div.Background image is not responsive when i resize the browser.my code for this div is

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" style="height:270px;background:url('images/whatsapp1.png');background-size:100% 100%">
 </div>
```

please help how i can make this image responsive so that if i resize the browser the will remain same

Comment: `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1` is equivalent to `col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1`.

Comment: Hi! You solved the problem?

Comment: @ZeevKatz yes , problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the text on your image you should use **this:**

> ```
> padding: 12.5%;
> background-size: contain;
> -webkit-background-size: contain;
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQQHA.png');
> ```

**`background-size: cover;` don't save the real image size**

**[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/vb00L7sm/)**

Comment: +1 for the padding trick! Actually `background-size: cover;` does save the image proportions, it just doesn't necessarily display the whole image, i.e. it crops the image according to the element's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover;` on your `div`, which scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio. The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" style="height:270px;background:url('images/whatsapp1.png');background-size: cover;">
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eum5o32o/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`background-size: cover`**.

This will crop the image to maintain it's aspect ratio. This will not let the background image look stretched. Later you can change `background-position` for specific media sizes to show particular portions of the image.

P.S: Also avoid using inline styles if the styles do not have to be dynamic with some the back-end language like php.

Answer (score 0):

### Add this

{

```
padding:0px;
background-size:100%

}
```